# Symfony FormBuilderInterface creating wrong query on handleRequest

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I am using symfony2 on my backend serving as REST API. Everything was working fine, but as the database size grows the create/update operation is getting slower (currently ~13secs!!).

I debug the situation and found out that the `handleRequest()` on `FormInterface` was causing the problem.

POST request body

```
{
  "name": "Group1",
  "users": ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
}
```

I create a form in the backend using this recevied request.

```
$form = $this->formFactory->createNamed('group', 'group', $groupData, array('method' => $request->getMethod()));
```

and then, `$form->handleRequest($request);`

when the handleRequest is called, it generates this query alongwith the other ones, that is the problem.

```
db.users.find({}).sort([ ]);
```

It is loading the whole collection and this is because of this line while building the Form:

```
$builder->add('users',
              'document', 
              array('class' => 'Test\Bundle\CoreBundle\Document\User', 
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'property' => 'id'
                   )
             );
```

Am I doing something wrong in builder? Right now I have re-written my patch/post requests and loading only the required users, adding them to the group and persisting the group without FormInterface.

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using? Second parameter on `add()` method should be one of the stated in http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html , but you are using "document".

Comment: well, document is actually entity as per the documentation of symfony. Using 2.6.3

Comment: Any reason to down vote?